# mysql_init overwriting memory space

Tags: c

When I call `mysql_init(mysql);`, it is overwriting a `char` array. I do not understand what I am doing wrong. My code:

```
void prepare_mysql(MYSQL *mysql) {
    mysql_library_init(0, NULL, NULL);
    mysql_init(mysql);
}

void get_uid(char *src, char *dst) {
    int i, len, count = 0;
    len = strlen(src);
    for(i = 0; i != len; i++) {
        if(src[i] == '-') { // iterate until a - sign is found
            break;
        }
        dst[count] = src[i]; // save char into dst
        count++;
    }
    dst[count] = '\0'; // add null char at the end of char array, otherwise everything will explode...
    // dst is now: 389302
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // argv[1] is for example: 389302-8232
    char uid;
    get_uid(argv[1], &uid);
    printf("uid = %s\n", &uid); // prints: 389302 (correct)

    MYSQL conn;
    prepare_mysql(&conn);

    printf("uid = %s\n", &uid); // prints: 3 (the first char only.. why?)

    mysql_close(&conn);
    mysql_library_end();
    return 0;

}
```

If I call the `get_uid` function after I call `mysql_init`, I cannot call `mysql_close(&conn)` because I get a `Segmentation fault`. Please help, I cannot understand..

Edit:
I have added this in main:

```
char *uid = malloc(strlen(argv[1]));
```

And later in main, I call `free(uid);`. Now it seems to be printing correctly everywhere before I call free.

Comment: Running this under valgrind would let to catch the mistake immediately.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a char array - `uid` is only a char.

Comment: But I can print this: `printf("uid = %s\n", &uid);` after I call `get_uid`. It prints 389302 (correct). Only after mysql_init, it prints only '3'.

Comment: Welcome to the world of undefined behaviour. It only prints the correct value until you overwrite the memory used for uid that you didn't reserve.

Comment: I will try to malloc space for `char uid`.

Comment: @Nemdr You might be narrowly escaping from a hazard with `printf("uid = %s\n", &uid)`. It might have happened that the next immediate byte is a null-byte.

Comment: I have done this in main: `char *uid = malloc(strlen(argv[1]));` and later in main I call `free(uid);` and now it seems to print correctly everywhere.. and I call `get_uid` like this: `get_uid(argv[1], uid)`.